# normalized conditional mutual information

Tags: conditional-probability, mutual-information

I am learning mutual information and need to apply it to my data. I strongly need to find a normalized conditional mutual information to have a range within [0,1] instead of 0 to infinity in conditional mutual information. I search about such a problem and could not find any idea how to find the solution using, for example, the R program. I just wonder if there is any way to explain what is the normalized conditional mutual information and how to get it?

Comment: Why do you need a normalized value? // [You might be interested in a question of mine from last year.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/502630/247274)

Comment: @Dave Thanks a lot for your comment. I need it to have a finite value of the mutual information instead of getting the range from `0` to infinity. I have read your question and answers but I still cannot find any R package that can deal with conditional mutual information or even conditional adjusted mutual information as I really need to calculate the conditional of two variables given other variables.

Comment: The value of mutual information you get when you do the calculation will be finite.

Comment: do you mean the adjusted mutual information? how about conditional value?

Comment: Could you please show me an example.

Comment: You are adding up a finite number of finite quantities, so the result will be finite.

Comment: @Dave Thank you a lot for your help and time. I do have conditional values of more than 1 and I need them to be between 0 and 1. That will be easy for me to interpret as a strong or weak association.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127296/discussion-between-dave-and-maryam).

Comment: @Dave Yes sure. I am in the chat.