# Comparing 2 Likert Scales for 1 Population

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, dataset, ordinal-data, likert

I have two 5-point Likert scales (Strongly Disagree to Strongly Agree) and I want to compare the results within one population sample. *I expect participants to choose 'agree' or 'strongly agree' on both scales.*

My sample size is small and in my study, I have assumed that my data is not normal so I have utilised non-parametric tests throughout.

I have read that the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test can be performed, however, I have also read that this test compares one population in two situations i.e. before and after an intervention. This is not what I am after.

I have read about correlation (such as Spearman's rank) but a significant number of assumptions must be met.

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: i haven't touched upon correlation in my dissertation so i'm not keen on it, but i've read that it may be relevant to answer my research question. my hypothesis is that individuals who choose "agree" or "strongly agree" on one Likert will choose the same on the other scale. i'm quite confused to be honest.

Comment: You have a pool of individuals and you have asked them (at least) two research questions with answers on a 5-point Likert scale each. You are interested in how similar the answers to two questions are similar. Is my interpretation that correct? If not please correct me.

Comment: yes, i have asked individuals to rate their agreement to 2 statements, both having a 5-point likert scale. i expect those who rate 4/5 on one scale to rate the same on the other scale.

Comment: Assume your data is paired. If so, you could calculate the normalised mutual Information between the two scales. Or, if preferred, the mutual information can be transformed into a correlation. See answer to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502630/information-correlation/508153#508153

Comment: I do not think my data qualifies as paired. The participants filled in 1 questionnaire which contained (amongst other questions) 2 Likert Scale questions testing 2 completely different aspects (perception vs self-assessed knowledge). From what I've understood, paired data relates to gathering info at different points in time.

Comment: I am going through the data again and have seen that I only have 8 respondents to both Likert scales therefore I doubt how viable any statistical tests will be given this minimal sample size!

Answer (score 2):

The most common approach to your query would be to apply a test or a confidence interval to the Spearman correlation coefficient. Given a sample of pairs $(y_i,x_i),\, i=1,\ldots,n$, of continuous variables, the Pearson correlation coefficient is

$$
r_p = \frac{\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)(y_i -\bar y)}{\sqrt{\left[\sum_i(x_i-\bar x)^2\right]\left[\sum_i(y_i-\bar y)^2\right]}}.
$$

The Spearman correlation coefficient, say $r_s$, is obtained by replacing $(y_i,x_i)$ in $r_p$ by their respective ranks, or the mid ranks since here you have got ties.

You can accomplish this in `R` by the command

```
cor.test(rank(y), rank(x), conf.int = TRUE)
```

Alternatively, you may consider computing an *agreement coefficient*. Agreement coefficients are useful when you want, for instance, to assess if two instruments agree. For example, you may have two assays designed to measure the same thing, but neither is the gold standard. In this case, even if both assays were perfectly linearly related or perfectly correlated, they do not perfectly agree or yield identical answers, unless the line relating them is the identity line. For more details on this, check Lin (1998) A concordance correlation coefficient to evaluate reproducibility, *Biometrics* **45**, 255-268 and Fay (2005) Random marginal agreement coefficients: rethinking the adjustment for chance when measuring agreement, *Biostatistics* **6**, 171-180.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this still applicable if I'm not measuring the same thing? I'm measuring agreement for 2 completely different statements (perception vs self-assessed knowledge) and assuming that a relationship exists between the responses to both statements. I'm using SPSS for my testing.

Comment: I've mostly used agreement coefficients in binary observations, i.e. Cohen's kappa and I have very limited experience with variables on ordinal scales such as yours. My advice is to check the references above. I'm sorry, I don't know much about SPSS. Perhaps this [link](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/spearmans-rank-order-correlation-using-spss-statistics.php) may be helpful.